# Both upload/download from my server stopped

Tags: 14.04, server, amazon-ec2

My EC2 instance suddenly stopped to respond the upload and download requests (this instance was working without any problems almost a year), I couldn't find why this's happening. Webserver configuration: NGINX, php-fpm, Mysql, only one webapp is running. All pages are working fine, but if I upload/download something Chrome browser just returns `NO data received` error after some time (I've also tried with other browsers, no luck). PhpMyAdmin (another app) also stopped to export the files, same error message. All webserver related logs are empty, nothing specific. How to find what is blocking it? Where to dig?

**EDIT:** I noticed that everything works fine via VPN.. Is this can be an attack to my server? Or someone or something is blocking the request?

PS:// I've tried the app locally (on my local webserver, also Ubuntu 14.04), everything is working fine. And installed the PhpMyAdmin to my local server the same as I did in EC2, it is also working fine.